# Chrome Extension: Edit the current url on click and then redirect to the edited one

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am a psychology student and I read papers very often. The university libraries provide the access to the databases but I need to use library search engine and log in every time. Quite annoying. I found a way to avoid jumping around the pages.

Here is the method:

I add "ezp.lib.unimelb.edu.au" to the end of the target database address after I found a paper in Google Scholar, then it will redirect to the library login page.

For example, the paper's address is:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006899315008550

I modified it as:

http://www.sciencedirect.com**.ezp.lib.unimelb.edu.au**/science/article/pii/S000689315008550

I want to create a Chrome Extension to finish this job on click (too lazy). I tried for hours but it does not work.

---

Here is what I have done:

I have three files in a folder:

First file: manifest.json

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Damn! Take me to the library!",
  "description": "This extension automatically adds the 'ezp.lib.unimelb.edu.au' to the browser's address, allowing you to visit the databases bought by the library quickly",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "unimelb.png",
    "default_title": "Damn! Take me to the library!"
  },
  
  "background":{
    "scripts":["popup.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

Second file: popup.js

```js
function getCurrentTabUrlthenChangeIt(callback) {
  var queryInfo = {
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
  };

  chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
    
    var tab = tabs[0];

    var url = tab.url;

    callback(url);

    var newurl = url.replace('/',"ezp.lib.unimelb.edu.au/");

    window.location.replace(newurl);


  });

}
```

Third file: unimelb.png

---

When I load this folder into Chrome, it does not work.

It's the first time I use JS, anyone has any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I feel I have problems in how to get popup.js run on click, and some problems in url editing.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this even without clicking. You can use the [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for this URL pattern so that your script gets injected to this page. Then you can send a message to the background script using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` and your listener will create a link you want here and then just reload the tab using `chrome.tabs.update()` with the new URL.

**manifest.json**

```
{
 "name": "My extension",
 ...

  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/*"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
  }],
  ...
}
```

**content-script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({loadURL: true});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, response) {
     if (message.loadURL) {
         var newurl = sender.tab.url.replace("/", "ezp.lib.unimelb.edu.au/");
         chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: newURL})     
     }
);
```

This is my first answer to the StackOverflow Community, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do help!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making an extension, it would be a lot easier to make a bookmarklet which can be used in *any* browser...

- Right click on the bookmark bar
- Choose "Add page..."
- Under "Name", enter whatever you want "Journal redirect" or whatever
- Under "URL", copy and paste the following code (no spaces)

  ```
  javascript:(function(){location.href=location.href.replace('sciencedirect.com/','sciencedirect.com/ezp.lib.unimelb.edu.au/');})();
  ```

Now when you're on the page, click that bookmark and it'll redirect you.

---

**Update**: Try this code in the URL for other domains

```
javascript:(function(){var%20l=location;l.href=l.origin+l.href.replace(l.origin,'ezp.lib.unimelb.edu.au/');})();
```

Comment: So cool. Thanks! But a question is, the changes according to different databases, therefore I have to replace it based on target address.

Comment: The `replace` method can use a regular expression to target the domain, so do all the domains end in `.com`? What are some other examples?

Comment: Thank you so much! It works well and I also figure out how to write the chrome extension! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

manifest.json

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Damn! Take me to the library!",
  "description": "This extension automatically adds the 'ezp.lib.unimelb.edu.au' to the browser's address, allowing you to visit the databases bought by the library quickly",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "unimelb.png",
    "default_title": "Damn! Take me to the library!"
  },
  
  "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

---

background.js

```js
//Wait for click

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
   "file": "popup.js"
  }, function(){ 
   "popup.js";
   console.log("Script Executed ...");
  });
})
```

---

popup.js

```js
// Change the url to library when on click

var l=location;l.href=l.origin+l.href.replace(l.origin, '.ezp.lib.unimelb.edu.au');
```

They work well.

It's so cool to finish the first chrome extension. Thank for the help from Mottie.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking to edit the url based on some pattern can use the chrome extension [Edit Url by Regex](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-url-by-regex/ofhioacmkjbbalfidehfdecjfnllhdno?hl=en&authuser=0)

For example for the scenario in this post, while using the extension, you can provide the regex as **http.*/science/** and the value as **http://www.sciencedirect.com.ezp.lib.unimelb.edu.au/science/**
and click submit. The url will get updated as expected.