# Chrome Extension:redirect the current url with specific rules

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, redirect, google-chrome-extension

I am a researcher and I want to access academic papers via my university. I discovered the I can modify the URL to achieve this. The rules are replacing "." with "-" and adding ".proxy.findit.dtu.dk" to the domain.

For example:
From: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925838811021414
to: https://www-sciencedirect-com.proxy.findit.dtu.dk/science/article/pii/S0925838811021414

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990967/chrome-extension-edit-the-current-url-on-click-and-then-redirect-to-the-edited/34010953#34010953), I modified the code to:
First file: manifest.json

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Redirect via DTU",
  "description": "This extension automatically replace '.' with '-' and adds the '.findit.dtu.dk' to the browser's address, allowing you to visit the databases bought by the library quickly",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "DTU.png",
    "default_title": "Redirect via DTU!"
  },
  
  "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

Second file: popup.js

```js
// Change the url to library when on click
var l=location;
l.href=l.href.replace(/\./g, "-")
l.href=l.origin+l.href.replace(l.origin, '.proxy.findit.dtu.dk');
```

Third file: background.js

```js
//Wait for click

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
   "file": "popup.js"
  }, function(){ 
   "popup.js";
   console.log("Script Executed ...");
  });
})
```

The last file I included is a figure: DTU.png.
However, it does not work. There is some problem with popup.js. **I cannot replace "." with "-" and adding ".proxy.findit.dtu.dk" to the domain at the same time**. Only the adding is working. What I got after running the example was: https://www.sciencedirect.com.proxy.findit.dtu.dk/science/article/abs/pii/S0925838811021414

I am totally new at JavaScript. Any suggestions to solve this?
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning to `location.href` is tricky because it leads to navigation so you should do it in one operation:

```
location.href = 'https://' +
  location.hostname.replace(/\./g, '-') +
  '.proxy.findit.dtu.dk' +
  location.href.slice(location.origin.length);
```